# what does "considers most" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

> [The United States signed but has not yet ratified the Convention; however, the United States considers most of the Vienna Convention’s rules as representing customary international law.](https://books.google.com/books?id=i0sTiwJQMi0C&pg=PT34&dq=The%20United%20States%20signed%20but%20has%20not%20yet%20ratified%20the%20Convention;%20however,%20the%20United%20States%20considers%20most%20of%20the%20Vienna%20Convention%E2%80%99s%20rules%20as%20representing%20customary%20international%20law.&hl=fa&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit4fewjYLMAhUJiSwKHfuEAD4Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=The%20United%20States%20signed%20but%20has%20not%20yet%20ratified%20the%20Convention%3B%20however)

does it mean that US acting accord to Vienna Convention’s rules, rather than other(signed but not ratified one) until NOW?

Comment: It means the US is in no hurry to *ratify* the Convention, because they think *most* of it is already covered by existing / customary international law, so actually ratifying the treaty isn't a great priority. Doubtless before they *did* ratify it, they'd find a few minor points to quibble over as not being in the US's best interests; they probably therefore don't particularly want to fully commit themselves, since they're not likely to be able to push through any further changes to favour the US.

Answer (score 1):

*Considers* means **thinks and accepts**  here.

[Free Dictionary definition -](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/consider)

Def. 2. To *think* or deem to be; *regard* as: considered his friend a liberal on most issues

The US thinks that most of the rules represent already standard (customary international) law. Informally (however), the US takes the rules as universally accepted. The US considers the rules a fact of life, if not a strict treaty.

Thus, since the United States considers most of the Convention’s rules as representing customary international law, the US has signed but "has not yet ratified" it, and is in no rush to ratify it soon.